# Spatial statistics using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-statistics

I recently began a course in spatial statistics and I cannot get relevant examples in the Internet.

Using population data, how can I use ArcGIS 10.3 to perform simple statistical procedures on the same data.

Comment: Which procedures are you looking to perform?

Answer (score 1):

What exact procedures do you wish to perform?  There are many many geostatistical tools available in ArcMap. For just a broad overview ,here are some tutorials that deal with spatial statistics that may give you a better idea how to perform the procedures.

http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-str-001-geographic-information-system-gis-tutorial-january-iap-2016/spatial-statistics/

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/07/13/spatial-statistics-resources/

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6626d5cc81a745f1b737028f7a519521

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=020e1d9e9d2d44f9ae7da8663cf3bac5

http://www.colgate.edu/portaldata/imagegallerywww/9f6bbcda-184d-4f20-bf0f-05069a418363/ImageGallery/17_GEOG245_Tutorial9.pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYKDqnAqnUs